# I want to update value from DB. but my code won't work

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

Main

```php
public function update_sample(){
   
   $id3 = sanitize($this->input->post('id3'));
        
   $sample3 = sanitize($this->input->post('sample3'));

   if($this->session->userdata('position_id') != ""){
            $username = $this->model->get_users($this->session->userdata('user_id'))->row()->username;
            $query = $this->model->update_sample($data);
            $data = array(
                "success" => 1,
                "message" => 'Note: You have successfully updated');
        }else{
            $this->logout();
        }
        generate_json($data);
}
```

model

```php
public function update_sample($sample){
    $sql = "UPDATE test SET  sample=? WHERE id=? AND enabled= 1";
    $data = array($sample);
    return $this->db->query($sql, $data);
}
```

js

```
$("#table-grid").delegate(".btnUpdate", "click", function(){
        var id = $(this).data('value');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: base_url+'Main/view_details',
            data: {'id3': id},
            success: function(data){
                var res1 = data.result1;
                if(data.success==1){
                    
                    document.getElementById("sample3").value = res1[0].samples;

                    $('#update').modal();
                }           
            }
        });
    });
```

I want to update Data from database I've been stuck here for long.

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to resolve the problem?

Comment: the problem is my data won't update but success msg show up.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Comment: Yes, that your message shows is logical, you dont check if the post is successfull or not. you simply fill you array, not depending on the outcome of previous code. Also, where is the definition of data? `$query = $this->model->update_sample($data);` i dont see it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how your class is created, but it looks like your function only returns true for query execution, you'll need to check for **"affected_rows"**.

Try the code below, with a little luck it may work, otherwise you have to check the **$result** variable and modify the code corresponding to the result.

```
public function update_sample($sample){
    $sql = "UPDATE test SET  sample=? WHERE id=? AND enabled= 1";
    $data = array($sample);
    $result = $this->db->query($sql, $data);
    return $result && $result->affected_rows > 0 ? true : false;
}
```